# Will VOX music player change anything in my iTunes library?

Tags: itunes, mac-appstore, music, third-party

I've downloaded the free [VOX music player](http://coppertino.com/vox/) from the Mac App Store after reading a recomendation in some site.

The program asks me for permission to acces my iTunes Library but a splash screen hints of some lenghty process is going to happen is I do so.

- Has someone used VOX, and what does is do to my iTunes Library ?
- Does it create its own library of sorts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see using Vox, it does **not** create a library of its own, instead it either access the iTunes Library directly for information.

It should be a read-only access, and you have nothing to worry.

You should note that it's not iTunes integration, so it does **not** work with iTunes Match to provide tracks that aren't downloaded to your Mac yet.

If you have further concerns, I suggest you contact the developers of Vox directly.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used it, but from what I have read it imports your iTunes library to use as a source. See [this thread](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?p=17232473#post17232473) on MacRumors.